# Ingest Node Elasticsearch While pushing data from MySQL to Elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, logstash

I am a windows Developer recently exploring elasticsearch. I was wondering if there is a way to bind a field to another one such that the values of the binding field are entered into the binded field.

> For Example: In windows development: I can bind the value of a
>   `textblock` to a `string` property and when I populate the `string`
>   property, the textblock text automatically gets updated. Similar in
>   `MS Excel`, I can put the value of one cell into another by simply
>   binding it.

### What Exactly Am I doing

I am using `elasticsearch` to hold location data. now I have a `latitude` field and a `longitude` field. I have another field `geo_location` of type `geo_point`.

### What I want to achieve

I want that each time i push some data into the index that has a `latitude` and `longitude`(it'll always have latitude and longitude), the `geo_location` field gets populated automatically from the newly pushed data's `latitude` and `longitude`.

Is that even possible? If yes then can anyone tell me how? or tell me what is this process called so that I can look up a documentation on it.

The `logstash.config` file has the below code for `output {}` to push data to elasticsearch index.

```
  elasticsearch 
  {
   index => "mytestproject_locationbase"
   document_type => "uap"
   hosts => "localhost:9200"
  }
```

How do I tweak the output code to **not delete the existing index** and then pre-process `latitude` and `longitude` fields to put into a geo_point type field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using a [pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/ingest.html). You can create a pipeline that moves a field either around or copies it (or removes it), thus you can create the required JSON structure to store a geo point.

Comment: Will it be possible if I am pushing the data from logstash (via SQL)?

Comment: The elasticsearch logstash output supports specifying a pipeline, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-pipeline